# asp.net mvc returning joined data to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a problem with returning data to view. I want to create a structure like category->subcategory and when I trying to run app, dont compiling. I have an error:

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable < string > to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable < mobile_store.Models.SubCategoryModel >

This is model:

```
public class CategoryJoinModel
    {

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<SubCategoryModel> SubCategoryList {get; set;}
    }
```

second model

```
public class SubCategoryModel
{
    public string SubCategory_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var joinedData = from c in db.category
                         from o in db.sub_category
                         where c.CAT_ID == o.CATEGORY_CAT_ID
                         select new
                         {
                             CategoryJoin = c.CAT_Name,
                             SubCatategoryJoin = o.SUBC_Name
                         };


        var gruped = from d in joinedData
                     group d by d.CategoryJoin
                     into g select new CategoryJoinModel
                     {
                         Category = g.Key,
                         SubCategoryList = new List<SubCategoryModel>(g.Select(s=>s.SubCatategoryJoin))
                     };
        return View(gruped.ToList());
    }
```

Index View

```
    @model IEnumerable<mobile_store.Models.CategoryJoinModel>
    @helper DisplayCat(mobile_store.Models.CategoryJoinModel cat)
    {
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => cat.Category)
  <ul>
  @foreach (var item in cat.SubCategoryList)
  {
    @DisplaySubCat(item)
  }
  </ul>
}

@helper DisplaySubCat(mobile_store.Models.SubCategoryModel subCat)
    {
  <li>@MvcHtmlString.Create(subCat.SubCategory_Name)</li>
}

@foreach (var cat in Model)
{
  @DisplayCat(cat)
}

@if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
   <i>no categories</i>
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when assigning the `SubCategoryList` property. It must be a `List<SubCategoryModel>`:

```
var gruped = 
    from d in joinedData.ToList()
    group d by d.CategoryJoin into g 
    select new CategoryJoinModel
    {
        Category = g.Key,
        SubCategoryList = g.Select(s => new SubCategoryModel 
        { 
            SubCategory_Name = s.SubCatategoryJoin 
        }).ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Now I have an LINQ error:The component of LINQ to Entities are supported only constructors and initiators with no parameters

Comment: @lukaszb, I have updated my example by calling `joinedData.ToList()` in the second query to eagerly fetch the results. Is it working better?

Comment: @lukaszb, if this post was helpful you may consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.